# Banach fixed point theorem: an example

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $F : X\rightarrow X$ be a smooth map. Suppose that $x_∗ \in X$ such that $F(x_∗) = 0  $ and the Frechet derivative $DF(x_∗)$ is invertible. I want to apply the **Banach fixed point theorem** to the operator $$G(x)=x-DF(x)^{-1}F(x)$$
but I need to first find a closed set to restrict the $G$ to. Can someone help me out? The question gives the following hint: There exists a closed ball $B$ about $x_∗$ such that $\| DG(x)\| \leq 1/2$  for all $x ∈ B$.

Comment: Are you sure it is $DF^{-1}DF$?

Comment: No. but $G(x_*)=x_*$ and $DG(x_*)=0$

Comment: No. I mean in the definition of $G$, since currently $G$ is zero.

Comment: No. That's all I have.

Comment: Sorry. I just corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have by definition of $G$ that
$$
DF(x)(G(x)-x)=-F(x).
$$
Since $DF(x^*)$ is invertible, we have by the smoothness of $F$ and the  implicit function theorem that
$$
D^2F(x)(G(x)-x)+DF(x)(DG(x)-I)=-DF(x)
$$
for all $x\in V$, where $V$ is a neighborhood of $x^*$. Thus we have
$$
DG(x)=DF(x)^{-1}D^2F(x)DF(x)^{-1}F(x),\quad x\in V.
$$
Since $F(x^*)=0$, we have by the smoothness of $F$ that $|DG(x)|\le 1/2$ around $x^*$.

Comment: How did you get rid of the term $G(x)-x$?

Comment: I used the definition $G(x)-x=-DF(x)F(x)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the very last sentence? I feel like the argument is not rigorous enough?

Comment: @Teodorism Since $DF(x^*)$ is invertiable, we know $\|DF(x^*)^{-1}\|>0$. Then by the smoothness of $F$, we see there exists a small neighborhood $V$ of $x^*$ and a constant $C$ such that it holds for all $x\in V$ that $\|DF(x)^{-1}\|\le C$ and $\|D^2F(x)\|\le C$ (with appropriate operator-norms). Then we can use the fact that $F(x^*)=0$ to show that $DG(x)$ is small near $x^*$.

Comment: One last question, how do you show that $G(x)\in V$ for all $x\in V$? Because I need that to use the Banach Fixed Point.

Comment: @Teodorism Note that the mean value theorem also holds for Frechet differentiable maps, so the fact that  $|DG|<1$ in $V$ implies that $|G(x)-G(x^*)|<|x-x^*|$. Since $G(x^*)=x^*$, we see  $G(x)\in V$ if $x\in V$.

Comment: Thank you. For proving that $G$ is contraction, can I do the following:
$$ \| Gx-Gy\|\leq \max\|DG\| \| x-y\| \leq (1/2)\| x-y\| $$
where for the first inequality I've used the MVT.